# Good idea to run a PHP file for a few hours as cronjob?

Tags: php, cron

I would like to run a PHP script as a cronjob every night. The PHP script will import a XML file with about 145.000 products. Each product contains a link to an image which will be downloaded and saved on the server as well. I can imagine that this may cause some overload. So my question is: is it a better idea to split the PHP file? And if so, what would be a better solution? More cronjobs, with several minutes pause between each other? Run another PHP file using exec (guess not, cause I can't imagine that would make much of a difference), or someting else...? Or just use one script to import all products at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your hardware can afford it and your process doesn't run out of memory - why not?

Comment: Point, still wondered or this is really the way to go, so was curious to your opinion.

Comment: Same as @LarsStegelitz but one small addition is that I recommend you implement a tracking system for the most recent successful image download in case something crashes then you know where it left off. This of course implies that at some point the cron job restarts itself before morning.

Comment: It's either not a bad idea to split the work (would make the process more robust in case of failure - but means additional overhead in code & data). Depends a bit on the use case.

Comment: many many options, only you know the best for your situations. but with php i would aim for at least as many processes as cores you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on how you've written it in terms of whether it doesn't leak open files or database connections.   It also  depends on which version of php you're using.   In php 5.3 there was a lot done to address garbage collection:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php

If it's not important that the operation is transactional, i.e all or nothing (for example, if it fails half way through) then I would be tempted to tackle this in chunks where each run of the script processed the next x items, where x can be a variable depending on how long it takes.   So what you'll need to do then is keep on repeating the script until nothing is done.

To do this, I'd recommend using a tool called the Fat Controller:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net

It can keep on repeating the script and then stop once everything is done.   You can tell the Fat Controller that there's more to do, or that everything is done using exit statuses from the php script.   There are some use cases on the Fat Controller website, for example: http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/use-cases.html#generating-newsletters

You can also use the Fat Controller to run processes in parallel to speed things up, just be careful you don't run too many in parallel and slow things down.   If you're writing to a database, then ultimately you'll be limited by the hard disc, which unless you have something fancy will mean your optimum concurrency will be 1.

The final question would be how to trigger this - and you're probably best off triggering the Fat Controller from CRON.

There's plenty of documentation and examples on the Fat Controller website, but if you need any specific guidance then I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, it helped me a lot :) We've implemented the cronjobs and everything's running smoothly

Comment: You're welcome!   Did you use the Fat Controller in your solution?

Comment: Yes and it works quite well, as far we have experienced. After your explanation, we were first looking for a shell script solution to create chunks (we thought it would be a cleaner solution), but that did not seemed so easy to develop. In contrast, Fat Controller is! :)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the previous answer, the best solution is to optimize your scripts:

- Prefer JSON to XML, parsing JSON is faster (vastly).
- Use one or few concurrent connection to database.
- Alter multiple rows in one time (Insert 10-30 rows in one query, select 100 rows, delete multiple, not more to not overload memory and not less to make your transaction profitable).
- Minimize the number of queries. (following previous point)
- Skip definitively already up to date rows, use dates (timestamp, datetime).
- You can also let the proc whisper with usleep(30) call.
- To use multiple PHP process, use [popen()](http://fr.php.net/popen).

Comment: Well parsing JSON in faster, but you cannot stream parse jsons, like you can XML-s, and if you have a 1-2 GB json, you will run out of memory, only for turning it into an object.