# A reliable daemon using Upstart & PHP for querying a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, daemon, upstart

So I'm building a PHP script that will query a MySQL database, check for new entries, and perform a multi_curl() function to send that data to an external API.

I only want one instance of this script running at a time, and I need it to check for new entries every 5 seconds. (I considered using a cron job for this, but once per minute is not quick enough.)

So I have created a daemon for use with Upstart:

**Sender.conf**

```
description "Sender"
author      "Trevor"

start on started httpd
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec php5 -q /path/to/script.php
```

Then, in the script file, I put an iteration counter variable, so that I can exit the script and restart it after so many executions. (This is to avoid any memory issues with long-running PHP script.)

**Script.php**

```
$iteration = 1;

while($iteration < 100) :

    doJob();

    $iteration++;

    sleep(5);

endwhile;


function doJob() {

    // Connect to database

    // Perform CURL operations

}
```

Does anyone foresee any issues with this method? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Unfortunately I'm stuck with PHP for the time being, and need a simple solution.

What about reliability? Is there a way to use a cron job in conjunction with Upstart to make sure that the process is still running (every 5 minutes or so)?

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago and I think some of the points are valid here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436112/good-idea-to-run-a-php-file-for-a-few-hours-as-cronjob/19436299#19436299 ) I think running PHP in a loop like this may well run into memory and resource issues, plus - what if it fails?   You'll then need a watchdog (another daemon) to check the process is alive and restart it.   I'd recommend taking a look at [the Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Thanks @SlappyTheFish -- I actually agree with you and went with a cron job on a 1 minute interval for precisely that reason. I looked at the Fat Controller and that actually looks like a fantastic solution.

Comment: Great stuff - just let me know if you need any help setting the Fat Controller up, I'd be glad to help.